# Html outline format

Tags: html

I need to break down a project into a outline  - I saw some "section" tabs for html5 but I could not get them to work. Is there another accepted format for statdardized outlines ?  I just came up with this html on my own - there might be a better way to do it.

```css
p.envelope {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 700px;
  /*display: inline ; */
}
```

```html
<p class="envelope">
  blah blah
</p>

<ol>
  <li>Point One </li>
  <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
    <li>Point One a</li>
    <li>Point Two b </li>
    <li>Point Three c </li>
  </ol>
</li>
```

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<ol>` as a child of another `<ol>`

Comment: @j08691 Yes, although you should explain that you CAN nest lists, so long as the subordinate list is contained within a `<li>...</li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to nest lists within other lists, is to put the nested list within a parent list item.

```
  <ol>
      <li>Main Point One: 
          <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
              <li>Point One a</li>
              <li>Point Two b </li>
              <li>Point Three c </li>
          </ol>
       </li>
       <li>Main Point Two</li>            
   </ol>
```